# python relative import with docker and uvicorn

Tags: python, docker, uvicorn

I have a directory structure like this on the host (outside docker container):

```
docker_ml/
├── auth.conf
├── data_loader.py
├── db.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── Dockerfile2
├── __init__.py
├── ml
├── models.py
```

My Dockerfile has the important directives relative to this problem:

```
WORKDIR /project
```

And the docker compose this:

```
command:
  ["uvicorn", "ml:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0","--port","9001","--reload"]
volumes:
  - .:/project/ml
```

So essentially I am mounting a volume where of my application at `/project/ml` in the docker container and I run the command `"uvicorn", "ml:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0","--port","9001","--reload"` at the directory entrypoint which is `/project`.

The uvicorn servers starts fine but `__init__.py` has the following relative imports:

`from .db import engine`

And I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db'`

What am I doing wrong here ?